# PHP XML DomDocument values

Tags: php, xml, web-applications, domdocument

I'm getting some data through an API and it's returning XML in the shape of:

```
<SUBSCRIBER_ROW>
<SUBSCRIBER>
    <ACCOUNT_NUMBER Value="0123456789123"/>
    <FIRST_NAME Value="fakeFirstName         "/>
    <INITIAL Value="w "/>
    <SURNAME Value="fakeLastName        "/>
    <TELEPHONE_NUMBER Value="5551234"/>
    <TELEPHONE_AREA Value="403"/>
```

The code I have to pull out the data is as follows:

```
   protected function par_getSubscriber($webCBSXML, $isJSON = false){
  ////parse XML
    $msg = 'WebCBS ERR: ';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    if(@$dom->loadXML($webCBSXML)) {
        $errors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Error');
        if($parsedData = self::checkError($dom)) {
            $parsedData = self::formatOutput($parsedData, $isJSON, true);
            return $parsedData;
        } else {
            $subscriber['account_number']      = $dom->getElementsByTagName('account_number')->getAttribute('Value');
            $subscriber['first_name']          = $dom->getElementsByTagName('first_name')->getAttribute('Value');
            $subscriber['surname']             = $dom->getElementsByTagName('surname')->getAttribute('Value');
            $subscriber['telephone_number']    = $dom->getElementsByTagName('telephone_number')->getAttribute('Value');
```

However, the whole script dies right after this line:

```
$subscriber['account_number']      = $dom->getElementsByTagName('account_number')->getAttribute('Value');
```

I don't have much experience dealing with DOM documents and since it's creating an object out of the XML I'm unable to use var_dump/print_r to see the structure of it!

Comment: Don't forget that XML element names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would suggest to use XPath to extract the information you need, it seems that you just misunderstood the return value of `getElementsByTagName()`. It returns a DOMNodeList not a single node. Also you have to uppercase the node names as @salathe mentioned. Change the code to something like :

```
$subscriber['account_number'] =
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('ACCOUNT_NUMBER')->item(0)->getAttribute('Value');
```

Also you should check that the nodes a really present in the XML. You can write the checks in PHP or you can use a schema language like XSD.

Comment: Even when I use:` $subscriber['account_number']      = $dom->getElementsByTagName('account_number')->item(0)->getAttribute('Value');` the code is dying right after that line. If I echo before and after that line the line before echo's, the line after does not.

Comment: What does the error log say? Can you `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` just before the line?

Comment: I love you for that line. I couldn't get errors to display before! `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in /home/bkilshaw/public_html/webcbs/Class-WebCBS.php on line 1196`

Comment: Hehe.. Don't forget to disable it for production. Instead of using `ini_get()` in the code directly you should consider to set it in the php.ini. Disabled on production servers, may be enabled on development servers. If using display_errors wont fit because it breaks something (maybe JSON responses etc) then don't forget that you have a log file! ;)

Comment: The comment on my original question, mixed with your reply, got me the answer. The XML is case sensitive so `$subscriber['account_number'] = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ACCOUNT_NUMBER')->item(0)->getAttribute('Value'); worked great!